# Non-linear ODE a variety

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me with the solution to the following diff equation.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y-x)(a-by)}{(1-x)(a-2by+bx)}$ with $x,y \in [0, \frac{a}{b}]$

I know the trivial solution (y=1) but struggling to find another solution.

Thanks.